# word-wrap: break-word; não está funcionando na vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css

vejam um exemplo funcional neste [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhb1usxq/1/)

o texto: "texto deveria ser quebrado" ele não está quebrando e respeitando o espaço da td.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E também não esta funcionando na horizontal, então o problema não é no `transform`, mas sim a falta do `width`, já que o elemento é um `<p>` dentro de um `td` você pode usar `width: 100%;`

> **É importante** notar que texto vaza devido aos suas margens negativas

Veja os testes:

```css
 p.horizontal
 {
     margin-left: -50px;
     margin-right: -50px;
     color: rgb(166,166,166);
     font-size: 18px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-family: Arial;
     width: 100%;
 }


 p.vertical
 {
     margin-left: -50px;
     margin-right: -50px;
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
     -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
     -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
     color: rgb(166,166,166);
     font-size: 18px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-family: Arial;
     width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>titulo</td>
    <td rowspan=4><p class='horizontal'>texto deveria ser quebrado</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br><br><br><br>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>titulo</td>
    <td rowspan=4><p class='vertical'>texto deveria ser quebrado</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Como disse anteriormente**É importante** notar que texto vaza devido aos suas margens negativas, então você pode fixar a largura e altura do elemento `<p>`, por exemplo:

```css
 p.horizontal
 {
     color: rgb(166,166,166);
     font-size: 18px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-family: Arial;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
 }


 p.vertical
 {
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
     -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
     -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
     color: rgb(166,166,166);
     font-size: 18px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-family: Arial;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>titulo</td>
    <td rowspan=4><p class='horizontal'>texto deveria ser quebrado</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br><br><br><br>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>titulo</td>
    <td rowspan=4><p class='vertical'>texto deveria ser quebrado</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela otima resposta e explicação

Comment: Apenas me restou uma duvida, no caso se esse texto vier maior que a largura de 150px; ele iria ultrapassar a caixa, como podemos fazer que essa largura seja responsiva?

Comment: @JulioHenrique creio que pode usar o `height: auto` (já que a sua largura rotacionada seria a altura do `<p>`)